# How to create a replay button and reset contents?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a `replay` button so the user can simply replay instead of going back to the level selection menu in a game I'm creating. The game is a `sprite-kit` game for `iOS 7`. The problem I'm having is resetting the integer. For some reason it stays at 0. All the rest of the scene contents replace themselves in the `initWithSize` method but even though I declare the integers value of 5 in the `initWithSize` method, it doesn't reset the value, instead it stays at 0.

After the `gameOverNode` for my game appears, there is a button that says "`Replay`", which I've set up to load the scene, this is the code:

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"reTry"]) {
    level2 *repeat = [[level2 alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:repeat transition:[SKTransition fadeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] duration:0.5]];
}
```

And as stated, everything in the scene resets (i.e. positions of `SKSpriteNodes`, etc), except for the value of the integer, which stays at 4.

Why is this, and how can I reset the value of the integer?

Is there a way to clear the scene before reloading it?

This is the `initWithSize` method:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        movesRemaining = 4;
```

Comment: what integer? self.size? show the code where it is supposed to reset to 5

Comment: See code above @connor "movesRemaining"

Comment: do you use that same method when the game first starts? does it work then?

Comment: Yeah i do, and yeah it loads properly. Maybe it's because I'm reloading it from the same scene? not sure. @connor

Comment: have you made sure that the line is getting called? either by adding an NSLog or breakpoint

Comment: Both @connor it's reading it just not changing it for some reason

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52484/discussion-between-connor-and-user3576196)

Comment: Where have you declared the movesRemaining variable?

Comment: Is it an instance variable ? property ? local variable ?

Comment: probably declared as static, am i right?

Comment: int movesRemaining is declared above the private interface, below the #imports @akashg

Comment: @prototypical declared above private interface, and below the #Imports so i think that's local right? (new to objective-c)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D not static, just int movesRemaining, then the value is set in the initWithSize method - movesRemaining = 4

Comment: Would be helpful if **in the question** you showed the code where the variable at question is being declared. This many comments turns this all into coding charades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have declared is a class object. You need to declare it as an instance variable instead.

Instead of

```
#import <SKScene/SKScene.h>
.
.

int movesRemaining;
```

You need to declare it like so:

```
@interface level2 : SKScene
{  
    int movesRemaining;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks worked like a charm :) appreciate it. @akashg